# How to build a softphone (using SIP protocol) using C#

Tags: c#, voip, sip

I have this challenge to build an sip softphone using c# or .net technologies.

Please guide me the technology, requirements and specifications that is needed to build such.

**Possible requirements:**

***Supported codecs:***

G.722.1, G.723.1, G.726, G.728, G.711, G.729, G.723.1, iLBC,: G.711 (A and m-law),G.729A/B/D/E, AMR, GSM 6.10/EFR, iLBC, Speex

- ***Voice:***

  Real time Quality Monitoring (MOS) 3
  independent phone lines
  Auto-Answer/Do Not Disturb Call
  Forwarding Full Duplex Audio
  Recording compress the audio data.
- Fully SIP compatible softphone/dialer
  for PC2Phone and  Mobile2Phone
  (iPhone, Nokia N95) application with
  symbian s60 , full source code should
  provide.
- Compatible with Windows 2000/XP/2003/Vista/Mac
- NAT/Firewall traversal feature
- Works with any 3rd party SIP Server
- Supports SIP outbound proxy
- Displays callers account balance
- Displays call credit time
- Automatic Echo Cancellation
- Automatic jitter buffer adjustment
- Last number Redial
- History of 10 last dialed numbers
- Quick dial user list
- Quick provision for customers, only
  user name and password required

Comment: Refer these links for furthur knowledge
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SIP_stack_with_SIP_proxy.aspx
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498056/c-sip-stack-library

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498056/c-sharp-sip-stack-library

Answer (score 1):

Konnetic provide fully managed SIP components for .NET development.

Their [SIP .NET](http://www.konnetic.com/products/products_sip_sdk_std.aspx) SDK is available here and is probably the most comprehensive. They also provide an MSRP library.

Otherwise, Microsoft's Lync server comes with a very good managed SIP library, available here: www.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Update: Domain is now for sale, and Konnetic is now a fly-fishing technology.

<s>http://www.konnetic.com is a relatively new addition. Fully managed. Everything you need to work with SIP and SDP. They haven’t picked the low-hanging fruit in the standard like a lot of the others.</s>

---

Just as good but tied to Microsoft is the Microsoft Lync server.