# Is it possible to send a SIP notify message programmatically to a registered SIP device?

Tags: perl, sip

Is it possible to create and send a SIP packets programmatically to a registered SIP device ?
I would like to send a SIP notify message, something like shown below:

```
      NOTIFY sip:alice@alice-phone.example.com SIP/2.0
      To: <sip:alice@example.com>;tag=78923
      From: <sip:alice@example.com>;tag=4442
      Date: Mon, 10 Jul 2000 04:28:53 GMT
      Contact: <sip:alice@vmail.example.com>
      Call-ID: 1349882@alice-phone.example.com
      CSeq: 31 NOTIFY
      Event: message-summary
      Subscription-State: active
      Content-Type: application/simple-message-summary
      Content-Length: 503

      Messages-Waiting: yes
      Message-Account: sip:alice@vmail.example.com
      Voice-Message: 4/8 (1/2)
```

I would like to use Perl for sending this information to a SIP device.
I am new to the SIP world, so my question might sound ambiguous . But any help on the same would be really appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, sure, it's just an IP packet. For Perl, my first try would be Net::SIP from CPAN.

Or if you want to keep it really simple, look at the code in this message: http://archive.cert.uni-stuttgart.de/bugtraq/2005/07/msg00276.html

To be standards-compliant, you need to handle SUBSCRIBE messages from your phones and send NOTIFYs only to those who are subscribed - but as your example seems to be taken directly from  RFC 3842, I guess you know that already. :)

Answer (score 0):

SIP is a text-based protocol that runs over IP, just like HTTP does. This makes it possible to write a SIP client in nearly any programming language.  Of course it's far easier when you use a SIP stack.  @Marie's suggestion looks good for PHP. The Java world of course has several very mature SIP stacks, eg, [JAIN](https://jain-sip.dev.java.net/).  And C# does too: see this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498056/c-sip-stack-library).