# Looking for a good SIP implementation in C#

Tags: c#, sip, .net-micro-framework

I saw a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498056/c-sip-stack-library) from 1.5 years ago and I am hoping there is something better.

I am looking for a totally managed C# implementation because I need it for the .NET Microframework, so I can't have .NET wrappers around C code.

Has anyone run into a good C# implementation of the SIP protocol.  I should not that I don't care about codecs, mostly will be dealing with call control.

Comment: Do you realize how slow this could be?  Depending on the device, you could do something in C maybe.

Comment: @leppie Why would it be slow?  The chip is an ARM7 running at 72Mhz.  Right now it's also running a web server, pretty successfully, I'd say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My own C# SIP stack is at [sipsorcery](http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/). It's far from perfect but as far as the RFC3261 core SIP standard goes it should be pretty good and you can hook into that using only SIPSorcery.Core assembly. The server applications can be disregarded if you're looking at doing some specialised call control.

Comment: That's pretty cool.  Call control is really the only thing I am looking for.  Do you have a sample anywhere on how to hook into the SIPSorcery.Core assembly?

Comment: There is a sample on the codeplex site in the softphone project http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/51179#299806, I think it still builds. One word of caution is that I haven't had many developers use the stack so the API isn't as clean as it should be. However it's a live project so if you hit a snag just post an issue on the codeplex site.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the ozeki voip sip sdk. It is written in c# and it provides a complete SIP implementation with all RFCs. The others I have tried were partial implementations only and didn't work with all my PBXs.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to be familiar with SIP protocol implementation then I suggest you to first read more useful information about the background of the VoIP technology. I used some examples for my project as well. I have found this explanation earlier:

The Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) is an IETF-defined signaling protocol widely used for controlling communication sessions such as voice and video calls over Internet Protocol. SIP helps in establishing communication sessions which involve various media types such as audio, video, or collaborative multimedia.

I mean, SIP protocol is very important to use when we would like to build an audio or video based application. (For example: Ozeki VoIP SIP SDK is appropriate to create SIP VoIP call services.)

The info derives from this webpage: http://voip-sip-sdk.com/p_304-sip-protocol-implementation-voip.html. I always use this website because this SDK has the best documentation which is plain and transparent to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

This [.NET SIP](http://www.konnetic.com/products/products_sip_sdk_std.aspx) SDK is probably the most comprehensive.