# Sip parser in c#

Tags: c#, parsing, sip, voip

I am looking for a library or class in c# that can parse sip packets.
I need  functions that will help me get the
Call-ID field from the packet, types of requests, and basically breakdown the sip packet to its fields.

Does anybody know something that can help me?
Thanks, ofek

Comment: I am using pcap.net to capture the packets

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498056/c-sharp-sip-stack-library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [class](http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#sipsorcery-core/SIPSorcery.SIP.Core/SIP/SIPHeader.cs) from my [sipsorcery](http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/) project can do it for you.

**Update**: If you have a string that contains a full SIP packet you can parse the full thing by using:

```
var req = SIPSorcery.SIP.SIPRequest.ParseSIPRequest(reqStr); 
var headers = req.Header;

var resp = SIPSorcery.SIP.SIPResponse.ParseSIPResponse(respStr);  
var headers = resp.Header;
```

If you don't know whether the SIP packet is a request or a response you can use the SIPMessage class:

```
var mess = SIPSorcery.SIP.SIPMessage.ParseSIPMessage(messStr, null, null);
var headers = SIPSorcery.SIP.SIPHeader.ParseSIPHeaders(mess.SIPHeaders);
```

**Update 2**:

Given you're using pcap.net to capture the SIP packets you are probably ending up with a block of bytes rather than a string. You can use the SIPMessage class to parse the SIP packet from a UDP payload:

```
var mess = SIPSorcery.SIP.SIPMessage.ParseSIPMessage(packet.Ethernet.IPv4datagram.Udp.Payload, null, null);
var headers = SIPSorcery.SIP.SIPHeader.ParseSIPHeaders(mess.SIPHeaders);
```

Comment: Thnaks you, but the problem is that I dont know what is the string that I should put in the function.   As I said, I am using pcap.net to capture the packets, so I have the "Packet" class. should I send the whole packet? or just the packet.Ethernet.IPv4datagram.Udp.Payload.ToString()??? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The SIP portion of your capture packet will be the UDP payload so Udp.Payload would seem to be the correct property. See further update.

Comment: One more thing if you can help me.. I need to get the source number and the destination number ( not IP, number). Thanks!

Comment: For destination number you probably mean the request URI (req.URI.User) and for source number take a look at the "From" header.

Comment: Hey again :) is there a way to get the SDP info from the SIP packets? I am trying to get the media port from the SIP packets in order to know which RTP packets belong to which SIP Packets