# C# SIP audio and video calling

Tags: c#, audio, video, call, sip

i am planning to make a c# windows application that is capable of audio and video VOIP-SIP calling having server on debian os(NGCP(Sipwise Next Generation Communication Platform)).so which could be best open source library for that to use?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search would've given you some valuable results. Such as this question:

[C# SIP Stack/Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498056/c-sharp-sip-stack-library)

Or this open source library for a server and client implemenation:

https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery